Disable dimmed region on tab
In iTerm2, how do I disable dimming out the region of the same window/tab that's not in focus?
I've tried setting the Dimming option to 1 in Appearance > Dimming, but to no avail. Checked the docs and all other options in Preferences, but didn't find one that suited my case.
Thanks!


I was struggling with adjusting the same setting. I found the solution in  this post

Awesome! Thanks
